# How to force "default" audio devices (maybe programmatically)?

Tags: macos, audio, development

Basically my question is similar to this [one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146591/change-default-audio-device): depending on my location, my Mac is connected to different audio devices.

Often, the Mac remembers that when I connect it to my dock in the office, that it should pick my USB headset for input/output. But not always.

I think there aren't any existing apps to help with this, but I am wondering: are there any "easy to use, say scripting", interfaces that one can use to write a bit of code that reacts to "events" and that could update sound settings programmatically?

Comment: Something like this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217148/using-apple-script-to-manage-sound-output-selection/218223#218223

Comment: Probably something like that yes ;-)